# Relation between $k$-sum failure and $P=NP$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, sat, big-picture, parameterized-complexity, fixed-parameter-tractable

If $P=NP$ then $W[1]=FPT$ holds. Hence $k$-sum conjecture fails at a finite $k$. What can we say about the time complexity of $SAT$ and the lowest $k$ at which $k$-sum conjecture fails?

In particular, do $3$-sum and $4$-sum conjectures fail if $P=NP$ and $3SAT$ is in $O(n^a)$ time for some upper bound $a\geq1$?

Comment: This is the other direction than what you are asking, but if you can solve $k$-sum in $n^{o(k)}$ time, then the Exponential Time Hypothesis (ETH)  is false (see Patrascu and Williams, On the possibility of faster SAT algorithms).

Comment: @Tassle yes correct I am asking for possible *effective* converse with a bound on $k$ given speed limits on $SAT$.

Comment: If I recall correctly, you can assume without loss of generality that the integers in your $k$-sum instance are in the range $-n^k$ to $n^k$ via hashing tricks. From there it is not too hard to encode such an instance of $k$-sum into a $3$-SAT instance with $O(kn\log n)$ clauses (using adder circuits and the like). This would imply that the $k$-sum conjecture fails whenever  $\lceil k/2 \rceil > \alpha$.

Comment: @Tassle So you are saying if $\alpha=1+\epsilon$, then $3$-SUM conjecture fails? Can you elaborate your comment for a full answer?

Comment: $\epsilon\in[0,1)$

Comment: If I didn't make any mistakes, then yes. I'll try to post an answer in a week or so if no one else has by then.

Comment: Could you please recall the formulation of the $k$-sum conjecture? This would make the question a but more self-contained.